# How can I avoid this SwiftUI + Combine Timer Publisher reference cycle / memory leak?

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine, xcode12

I have the following SwiftUI view which contains a subview that fades away after five seconds. The fade is triggered by receiving the result of a Combine TimePublisher, but changing the value of `showRedView` in the `sink` publisher's sink block is causing a memory leak.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showRedView = true

    @State var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if showRedView {
                Color.red
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            fadeRedView()
        }
    }
    
    func fadeRedView() {
        Timer.publish(every: 5.0, on: .main, in: .default)
            .autoconnect()
            .prefix(1)
            .sink { _ in
                withAnimation {
                    showRedView = false
                }
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

I thought this was somehow managed behind the scenes with the `AnyCancellable` collection. I'm relatively new to SwiftUI and Combine, so sure I'm either messing something up here or not thinking about it correctly. What's the best way to avoid this leak?

Edit: Adding some pictures showing the leak.

[image: Memory leak pic 1]

[image: Memory leak pic 2]

Comment: Views aren't supposed to be living instances with their own life-cycle. They just describe the view structure. Any kind of timers or async actions should happen externally, in a view model, that a view "observes".

Comment: Xcode 12b3 Instruments does not detect any leak in provided code. What is MemoryTest?

Comment: MemoryTest is just the name of the sample project. I can see the memory leak consistently (in both Xcode 12 beta 4 and Xcode 11.5) by checking the memory graph with malloc stack logging activated. Looking like it's related to the prefix operator. Thoroughly testing it now, but removing that operator is currently resolving the leak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Views should be thought of as describing the structure of the view, and how it reacts to data. They ought to be small, single-purpose, easy-to-init structures. They shouldn't hold instances with their own life-cycles (like keeping publisher subscriptions) - those belong to the view model.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   var pub: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        Timer.publish(every: 2.0, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
            .prefix(1)
            .map { _ in }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } 
}
```

And use `.onReceive` to react to published events in the View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showRedView = true

    @ObservedObject vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if showRedView {
                Color.red
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
        }
        .onReceive(self.vm.pub, perform: {
            withAnimation {
                self.showRedView = false
            }
        })
    }
}
```

---

So, it seems that with the above arrangement, the `TimerPublisher` with `prefix` publisher chain is causing the leak. It's also not the right publisher to use for your use case.

The following achieves the same result, without the leak:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   var pub: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        Just(())
           .delay(for: .seconds(2.0), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
           .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } 
}
```

Comment: FYI this actually also causes the same memory leak because of the use of `self` in the onReceive perform closure. Making `showRedView` a `@Published` property of the view model and moving the animation function to that class (so `weak self` can be used) resolves the issue.

Comment: How can you tell that it's a memory leak? Views are structs, value types, so there's no issue with strong references afaik. SwiftUI may retain some state variables but that's not a leak

Comment: There are reference cycle  issues with value types and closures. A really good discussion is here:

https://forums.swift.org/t/avoiding-unbreakable-reference-cycle-with-value-types-and-closures/18757

If you run a project with the code above and look at the memory graph, you can see the same malloc leak.

Comment: Also spoke too soon about it being resolved in my first comment here. Even if I move `showRedView` to the view model it still leaks. It's not 100% of the time in that instance - wonder if it's an Xcode beta issue

Comment: just checked Xcode 11.5, the leak is showing there as well.

Comment: @JAB, I checked the same, and though there is a leak (somewhere in UIApplicationMain), it's not the same as what you have your question. I copied the code in my answer verbatim into the project and ran it

Comment: Yes, I see that as well. it seems like using `onReceive` does not give a proper backtrace. It looks like it is specific to using the Combine publisher this way. For instance, if I change `showRedView` to an `@Published` property of the view model, and then update that with an animation delay in `.onAppear`, there is no leak.

Comment: Also, if you just remove the `onReceive` code from your, you will see the leak disappear. Looks like it's somewhere in that process.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. It might be caused by, but not specifically, that leak. If you nest this view inside an outer view, with some if condition to toggle it on and off, and then if you add some test class that prints `"init"`/`"deinit"`, you'd see that the test class instances get de-allocated each time the view is not shown.

Comment: It is definitely curious. Thanks for helping look into it.

Comment: Yeah, looks like prefix is leaking. Filed a radar (FB8365664). Using the Just publisher with delay does seem more appropriate - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're leaking because you store an `AnyCancellable` in `subscriptions` and you never remove it.

The `sink` operator creates the `AnyCancellable`. Unless you store it somewhere, the subscription will be cancelled prematurely. But if we use the `Subscribers.Sink` subscriber directly, instead of using the `sink` operator, there will be no `AnyCancellable` for us to manage.

```
    func fadeRedView() {
        Timer.publish(every: 5.0, on: .main, in: .default)
            .autoconnect()
            .prefix(1)
            .subscribe(Subscribers.Sink(
                receiveCompletion: { _ in },
                receiveValue: { _ in
                    withAnimation {
                        showRedView = false
                    }
                }
            ))
    }
```

But this is still overkill. You don't need Combine for this. You can schedule the event directly:

```
    func fadeRedView() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5)) {
            withAnimation {
                showRedView = false
            }

        }
    }
```